# Invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: php, json

I get "`Warning: json_encode() [function.json-encode]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in...`"  error in php. I don't want to escape invalid characters, I need them. How can i use invalid character in json_encode().
In mysql database, I am using "`utf8_general_ci`". (Thanks)

```
try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $dbh = null;
    $provinces = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($provinces ) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

Comment: What is your connection character set? Have you tried `$dbh->query('SET NAMES utf8;');` _before_ doing your query?

Comment: And if it's _really_ non-utf-8 data, well, the manual states: _"This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data."_, so you'll have to write your own json-encoder.

Comment: i do not get warning anymore, but still invalid characters can't be shown. 
"{"items":[{"id":"1","name":"Ilk"},{"id":"2","name":"\u011fi\u00e7"}]}"
How can i correct it too. (Thanks)

Comment: when i use ".getJSON()", it gives the correct result to html page. !!!Thanks both of you!!!

Comment: Nah, f* that second guy, I'll take sole credit here :P

Comment: it means, thank you two times :D

Comment: you should declare UTF8 directly inside the PDO connection as so: `new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8");` and on my side I also switched my tables from previously being like yours `utf8_general_ci` to a proper UTF charset as `utf8_general_ci`. But of course that is if you can change it on DB side. Maybe I should put this as an answer but since I'm not sure it really fixes your problem I'll leave it as a comment for now.